# check data from json file

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have 10 records in json file and I am appending those records in a list on page scroll. So, as long as I keep scrolling, the data gets appended.

What I want is when all the data present in the json file populated in the list , then no more data should be appended.

Comment: please provide some code for us to start helping you. Dont just say what you want,show us what you have tried.

Comment: and this does not seem to be a file issue, it seems more like logic issue within your list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time before you append data into the JSON, just check if the limit is reached or not ?

If its reached dont append any more.

Or you could keep a counter and increment the counter each time you append data into the JSON.

Check this counter before you update to check whether the limit has been reached or not.